# Can I replace metal porch swing components with wood?

Tags: wood, construction

Have a metal porch swing that we haven't used in 6 years because a weld broke on the slat in the back that holds the two ends together.  Wondering if I could replace the mesh fabric and the metal brace with wood slats and re-purpose this swing.  What kind of wood should I use and how should it be attached to the metal side pieces?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Home Improvement stack exchange. It would probably be helpful to include pictures of the swing and broken part(s).

Comment: How you do it is probably dependent on how much space is available for a back cushion if you go with wood slats. Choice of wood depends on how nice you want it to look :-).